# Ticket got created and ticket is created

Tags: tense

Could someone tell me which one is the correct sentence here:

> Ticket got created

or

> Ticket is created

This is the scenario:

Someone comes to me and asks for the status of his query.  I have to tell them about the help ticket.  Which one is correct of the above statements?

Comment: _Ticket has been created_ is better

Comment: Both are perfectly grammatical. Both are also perfectly unidiomatic. And I might add, both perfectly fail at actually answering that person's question.

Comment: Well... isn't "Ticket is created" a poor construction? Shouldn't it be "Ticket *was* created" at least?

Answer (score 4):

I think that because you are giving the current status of their query, you should use the [present perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html) tense.

> The ticket has been created.

This says that the ticket was created some unspecified time before now. If you could be specific about when the ticket was created, you would use the simple past tense:

> The ticket was created yesterday.

If you were explaining the current state of the ticket, you would use the present tense:

> The ticket is set to "Awaiting Customer Response".

If you were explaining an on-going activity related to the ticket you would use [present continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentcontinuous.html):

> The issue is being investigated.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with ЯegDwight. Though they are grammatical, there could be better way to tell that.

And I assume that we are talking about some system through which the asker has put his/her query. It generally happens with someone has some query or concern and wants to draw some department's attention. For instance, if the computer is too slow, I open a ticket for the IT department in my company. **If this is the case...**

there could be many ways to answer this. I work with PHP developers and often encounter such situations. And, we prefer ...

> The ticket has been generated/created

In fact this is the notification we put in most of the pop-ups. When the action is confirmed, we often describe that as **[Something] has been [something]** in software. But as I said, that's what I'd prefer.